# How to provide destination MAC address to socket

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, arp

I have an application on my linux host that communicates via UDP to another machine via 10G ethernet. The machine on the other end does not respond to ARP requests. I am able to get it's MAC address through other means (a different interface, on

Is there a way to programmatically get this information into the arp table w/out privileged status?

I know I can on a command line issue "sudo arp -s 1.2.3.4 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" every time I power it up.

I know I can add "1.2.3.4 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" to etc/ethers

I know that as a priviledged usr/process I can issue an ioctl to SIOCSARP.

All of these mechanism's require sudo/root access. I read something about giving the application "CAP_NET_ADMIN" permissions.

I'm looking for this capability so that the end users don't need to do any of the above. It seems like, If I, w/out sudo/root, can open a socket that determines the need for this network information, there should be a way for me, w/out sudo/root, to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't edit ARP information as non-root. This makes sense, as otherwise malicious attacker would be able to modify ARP tables and completely disrupt network communication and compromise security.

The solution to your problem is to fix your network configuration.

Comment: Yeah, functional ARP and ICMP would be nice, but I don't have control over the machine on the other end. It's provided by a 3rd party. In my question I was thinking more about, Is there a packet I can send that would cause the MAC info to be populated, but in hindsight, that would require root as well, as the only way to manually get a MAC into a packet is w/ a RAW socket.